# Div tags are not flowing in html

Tags: html

I am trying to create a newsletter using  tags to line up the data. I have created the following code:

```
<div style="width:410px; height:207px; background-color:#ffffff; float:left;">
    <p style="text-align:left; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; size:15px; line-height:20px; color:#000000; padding:0 10px 0 0;">
        <a href="hyperlink">
            <img align="left" src="image.png" width="190" height="207" style="width:190px; height:207px; border:none; padding:-10px 0 0 0;">
        </a>
        <a href="hyperlink" style="text-decoration:none; color:#00add0; font-weight:600;">text</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

However, when I view this design in Outlook mail, the second  doesn't fall below the first and crowds into the first along with the third instead.

Any thoughts on what I can try to do? Thanks!

OB

Comment: Not a solution, but you forgot to self-close the img element which can cause errors when rendering the HTML. It should end with />, not >.

Comment: also I do not think you need to specify the width of the image in two different languages you should probably stick with the HTML description. also you might consider doing a simple style section instead of with the element for example <style> P.1{text-align:left;font-family:Arial, Sans-serif;...} P.2{...} use the # for an id="" use . for CLASS=""</style>

Comment: @CS_STEM Styles get ripped out in many emails. To get consistent results you have yo use inline styles in emails.

Answer (score 0):

Add br tags where you want it to start on new line. `<br />` , you can even do `<br /><br />` as many times as you want to give it extra space.

```
<div style="width:410px; height:207px; background-color:#ffffff; float:left;">
  <p style="text-align:left; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; size:15px; line-height:20px; color:#000000; padding:0 10px 0 0;">
    <a href="hyperlink"><br />
      <img align="left" src="image.png" width="190" height="207" style="width:190px; height:207px; border:none; padding:-10px 0 0 0;"></a><br />
    <a href="hyperlink" style="text-decoration:none; color:#00add0; font-weight:600;">text</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following CSS code to your div element.

```
clear: both;
```

Here's are JSFiddle's [with](http://jsfiddle.net/U99ve/show/) and [without](http://jsfiddle.net/U99ve/1/show/) clear: both;

Actually, ignore that. Removing float: left; from all div elements will sort the trick - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U99ve/3/show/)

Answer (score 0):

Divs for emails is a baaaad choice, email clients usually ignore some css properties to protect it's users, you should use tables (yes, it's sad but true) and do simple designs for emails. I guess float is being ignored by the email client.

Comment: Tables are the way to go with emails.  You have to code like it's the '90s.

Answer (score 0):

just remove `float:left;` from `div` style

Answer (score 0):

Email clients do seem to prefer tables to divs, but divs aren't necessarily 'evil' in emails. You just can't expect the HTML rendering engine of Outlook to behave like Chrome or FireFox. So...code for the least common denom, right?

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:410px; height:207px; padding:0; margin:0; background-color:#efefef; float:left; text-align:left; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; size:15px; line-height:20px; color:#000000">
            <a href="hyperlink" style="text-decoration:none; color:#00add0; font-weight:600; padding-left:10px"><img align="left" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-g-190-207-10.jpg" width="190" height="207" style="width:190px; height:207px; border:none; padding:-10px 0 0 0;"/>text</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Your code was probably close to working. Think of the `<td>` as your `<p>` element, and the `<table>` as the `<div>`. In some ways, I think email markup is easier (lots of limitations, and fewer options -- forces one to keep it simple).

Since both your links were going to the same place, I wrapped your `<img>` inside the `<a>`, which is legit.

This ought to get you close, I think.

http://jsfiddle.net/KhE4B/